# Text is not updating through script Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity game and I have made a shop for upgrades. It has for some items, multiple levels of what you buy and some only has or hasnt got something. I want to display the new level you will be getting and if the item is bought but it is no updating the text in the update function. Sorry if this is a stupid question, im new to unity and cant find anything online. This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UpgradeManager : MonoBehaviour
{

[Header("Menu")]
public Base energy;
public GameObject gunner;
public GameObject carrier;
public GameObject baseObject;

[Header("BulletSplit")]
public BulletShoot bullet;
public GameObject BulletSpazerUpgradeButton;
public bool isBulletsSpazed = false;
public float costBulletSplit;
public Text bulletCostText;

[Header("BulletSpeed")]
public GameObject BulletFastUpgradeButton;
public float bulletSpeedCost = 100f;
public float bulletIncreaseSpeed = 75f;
public Text bulletSpeedCostText;
private bool hasGottenBulletSpeed;

[Header("HealthUpgradesGunner")]
public float numOfUpgradesHealthG;
public int[] amountUpgradesHealthG;
public int[] costsUpgradesHealthG;
public int wayInHealthUpgradeG = 0;
public Text healthUpgradeGunnerText;

[Header("HealthUpgradesCarrier")]
public float numOfUpgradesHealthC;
public int[] amountUpgradesHealthC;
public int[] costsUpgradesHealthC;
public int wayInHealthUpgradeC = 0;
public Text healthUpgradeCarrierText;

[Header("CarryAmountUpgrades")]
public float numOfUpgradesCarry;
public int[] amountUpgradesCarry;
public int[] costsUpgradesCarry;
public int wayInCarryUpgrade = 0;
public Text carryUpgradeText;

[Header("FasterFirerate")]
public float numOfUpgradesFirerate;
public float[] amountUpgradesFirerate;
public float[] costsUpgradesFirerate;
public int wayInFirerateUpgrade = 0;
public Text firerateUpgradeText;

[Header("Missiles")]
public float costMissiles;
public Text missileText;
[HideInInspector]public bool missilesUnlocked;

[Header("Build")]
public float costBuild;
public Text buildText;
[HideInInspector] public bool hasBuild;


private bool canvasIsShown;
private void Update()
{
    
    healthUpgradeCarrierText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost: " + costsUpgradesHealthC[wayInHealthUpgradeC].ToString() + "\n Amount: " + carrier.GetComponent<CarryerController>().maxHealth + " increased to " + amountUpgradesHealthC[wayInHealthUpgradeC];
    carryUpgradeText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost: " + costsUpgradesCarry[wayInCarryUpgrade].ToString() + "\n Amount: " + carrier.GetComponent<CarryerController>().maxPower + " increased to " + amountUpgradesCarry[wayInCarryUpgrade];
    healthUpgradeGunnerText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost: " + costsUpgradesHealthG[wayInHealthUpgradeG].ToString() + "\n Amount: " + gunner.GetComponent<GunnerController>().maxHealth + " increased to " + amountUpgradesHealthG[wayInHealthUpgradeG];
    firerateUpgradeText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost: " + costsUpgradesFirerate[wayInFirerateUpgrade].ToString() + "\n Amount: " + gunner.GetComponent<GunnerController>().fireRate + " increased to " + amountUpgradesFirerate[wayInFirerateUpgrade];
    if (isBulletsSpazed)
    {
        bulletCostText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Bought";
    }
    if (hasGottenBulletSpeed)
    {
        bulletSpeedCostText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Bought";
    }
    if (hasBuild)
    {
        buildText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Bought";
    }
    if (missilesUnlocked)
    {
        missileText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Bought";
    }

}
public void BuyHealthUpgradeG()
{
    if (wayInHealthUpgradeG < numOfUpgradesHealthG && baseObject.GetComponent<Base>().totalPower >= costsUpgradesHealthG[wayInHealthUpgradeG])
    {
        gunner.GetComponent<GunnerController>().maxHealth = amountUpgradesHealthG[wayInHealthUpgradeG];
        gunner.GetComponent<GunnerController>().health = amountUpgradesHealthG[wayInHealthUpgradeG];
        baseObject.GetComponent<Base>().totalPower -= costsUpgradesHealthG[wayInHealthUpgradeG];
        wayInHealthUpgradeG++;
    }
}

public void BuyHealthUpgradeC()
{
    if (wayInHealthUpgradeC < numOfUpgradesHealthC && baseObject.GetComponent<Base>().totalPower >= costsUpgradesHealthC[wayInHealthUpgradeC])
    {
        carrier.GetComponent<CarryerController>().maxHealth = amountUpgradesHealthC[wayInHealthUpgradeC];
        carrier.GetComponent<CarryerController>().health = amountUpgradesHealthC[wayInHealthUpgradeC];
        baseObject.GetComponent<Base>().totalPower -= costsUpgradesHealthC[wayInHealthUpgradeC];
        wayInHealthUpgradeC++;
    }
}

public void BuyCarryUpgrade()
{
    if (wayInCarryUpgrade < numOfUpgradesCarry && baseObject.GetComponent<Base>().totalPower >= costsUpgradesCarry[wayInCarryUpgrade])
    {
        carrier.GetComponent<CarryerController>().maxPower = amountUpgradesCarry[wayInCarryUpgrade];
        baseObject.GetComponent<Base>().totalPower -= costsUpgradesCarry[wayInCarryUpgrade];
        wayInCarryUpgrade++;
    }
}
void Start()
{
    BulletFastUpgradeButton.SetActive(true);
}


public void GetFastBulletsUpgrade()
{
    if(energy.totalPower >= bulletSpeedCost && !hasGottenBulletSpeed)
    {
        bullet.speed = bulletIncreaseSpeed;
        energy.totalPower -= bulletSpeedCost;
        hasGottenBulletSpeed = true;
    }
}
public void GetSpazerBulletsUpgrade()
{
    if (energy.totalPower >= costBulletSplit && !isBulletsSpazed)
    {
        isBulletsSpazed = true;
        energy.totalPower -= costBulletSplit;
    }
}

public void FastFireRate()
{
    if (wayInFirerateUpgrade < numOfUpgradesFirerate && energy.totalPower >= costsUpgradesFirerate[wayInFirerateUpgrade])
    {
        gunner.GetComponent<GunnerController>().fireRate = amountUpgradesFirerate[wayInFirerateUpgrade];
        baseObject.GetComponent<Base>().totalPower -= costsUpgradesFirerate[wayInFirerateUpgrade];
        wayInFirerateUpgrade++;
    }
}

public void MissileUpgrade()
{
    if (energy.totalPower >= costMissiles && !missilesUnlocked)
    {
        missilesUnlocked = true;
        energy.totalPower -= costMissiles;
    }
}

public void BuildGun()
{
    if (energy.totalPower >= costBuild && !hasBuild)
    {
        hasBuild = true;
        energy.totalPower = costBuild;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In general do not Update text in `Update` every frame but rather only in the moment the value actually changes. Then also you should store the references and not use `GetComponent` over and over again

Comment: Then note that everything like `healthUpgradeCarrierText.GetComponent<Text>()` is completely useless! `healthUpgradeCarrierText` already **is** a `Text` reference! So either you have it already then using `GetComponent<Text>()` just returns exactly the same reference => senseless .. or you don't have the reference then you will get an exception since you are trying to call a method on it ... remove all these `GetComponent<Text>()` on references that already are `Text` components ;)

Comment: @derHugo i actually had it like that (the not using GetComponent<>) but it wasnt working so changed it... any idea why it isnt  working though?

Comment: Your code is a bit complex to parse it here on a phone ^^ I suggest you start [Debugging your code with breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) yourself line by line and see where exactly it doesn't behave as expected ;) Unity components usually work so the issue is not in you setting the text but rather most probably the according line never being called at all or not with the value you think ;)

Comment: thankyou, ill try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Turns out there were 2 errors before from unity collab that are always there and then one went away but there was a nullreferenceexeption and I ignored it thinking it was a unity collab error.... i feel so stupid